# How can I add fonts to netbeans?

Tags: linux, ide, netbeans, fonts

I'm using netbeans on ubuntu, I would like to add some fonts to it. Could anyone tell me how this is done ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the IDE's editor font?

I'm on Windows with 6.1 but I assume the process will be the same.

```
Tools > Options > Fonts & Colours > Syntax
    Category: default
    Font: ([...]) > Select Font
```

Comment: and if you add new fonts to windows you need to restart IDE. Tested on windows 10 and Netbeans 8.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Adding them to the .fonts/ directory did the trick .

Comment: where is .font located?